# How to add percentage for y-axis in rechart?

Tags: recharts

I'm using reChart in my project how can I add "%" to y-axis in my chart?
I'm using rechart https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/SimpleAreaChart

Answer (score 13):

you can do it like:

```js
<YAxis
     tickFormatter={(tick) => {
     return `${tick}%`;
     }}
/>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that this can be simplified to: `<YAxis tickFormatter={tick => \`${tick}%\` } />`

Comment: Thanks!! this help me a lot

Comment: <YAxis domain={[0, 100]} tickFormatter={(value) => `${value}%`} />